# Conflicting between `\everydisplay` and `eqnarray` environment in `beamer` class

Tags: beamer, amsmath

In my presentation, I want every math to be blue and every display math to be red. In my attempt, I have tried to compile the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\everymath{\color{blue}}
\everydisplay{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{eqnarray}
a &=& b\\
c &=& d
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I got an error say **Improper `\halign` inside $$'s. \end{frame}**. If I disable `\everydisplay` command, there is no error. However, this is not my desire! I do want every display math to be typesetted in red. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Just avoid `eqnarray` in every circumstances.

Comment: @egreg Could you tell us the reasons why?

Comment: See [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use beamer's own commands to change colours.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{fg=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
c &= d
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
$a=b$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that you will get some unfortunate effects with equation labels if you use different colours for inline and displayed mathematics.

[image]

Comment: Great! I could actually read Beamer manual before posting this question :)

Comment: It's a long read...

Comment: You are right. Sometimes it is less efficient than surfing the internet or asking in the forum!